# Reducing time complexity of the code (max execution time is 16000 ms)

Tags: java, algorithm

Can someone help me out how to reduce time complexity of this code. Max execution time is 16000 ms.

```
public class count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long c = 0;
        
        for(long i=1L;i<=200000000000000L;i++) {
            c+=Long.bitCount((i));
        }
        
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s fixed - calculate it once and write it down. Otherwise, write out the binary form of the numbers 0 to 10 and and see if you can see a pattern.

Comment: I doubt that there is a more efficient way to *compute* this ... unless you figure out an (analytical) formula.  That is a maths problem (and off topic).

Comment: you are mixing concepts here: "time complexity" is O(1), there is no value that changes the run time; "max elapsed time" is a different thing. Maybe checking the number obtained for powers of 2 (continuation of Boris' thoughts in first comment) {one of the problems of Big-O notation - it is good to know about complexity, but not about the elapsed time}

Comment: @ user16320675 I got your point. but I'm not able to clear all the test cases from the above code. Is there any different way I can approach it?https://www.codewars.com/kata/596d34df24a04ee1e3000a25/train/java

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 number with just one bit (number 1, excluding 0).
Then, there are 2 numbers with exactly two bits (2 and 3)
After that, 4 numbers with exactly three bits exist (4, 5, 6 and 7) and it continues this way.

In general, there are 2 to the power of n-1 numbers with n bits.
Knowing this, you can calculate the number of bits by getting the number of bits of the last number and adding the bit counts of all previous numbers afterwards:

```java
public class count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long lastNum=200000000000000L;
        long bc=Long.bitCount(lastNum);
        long c=bc;
        //1<<n means 2 to the power of n
        c*=1L<<(c-1);//2 to the power of c-1 is the first number with c bits
        for(long l=1;l<bc;l++){//all numbers of bits until the 
            c+=l*(1L<<(l-1));
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

The time complexity of this code is O(log(n)) as bc is the binary logarithm of n and it loops from 1 to bc and all other operations in the loop are constant.